# How can I get the product details (like SKU) on JS when "Add to Cart" button is clicked?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, requirejs

I know how to extend the `catalogAddToCart` function and already successfully fired my codes when I go into product detail page and press **Add To Cart** button. But I still has a problem: how can I get the product details on the product to be added into cart, like SKU? Currently I use global variable to get it like this:

On `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/template/frontend/templates/cart/addtocart.phtml`

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "MyAddToCart": ""
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    var product_sku = '<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getSku(); ?>';
</script>
```

Then on `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'MyAddToCart': 'Vendor_ModuleName/js/MyAddToCart'
        }
    }
};
```

Finally on `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/MyAddToCart.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
], function($){
    "use strict";
    $.widget('Vendor.MyAddToCart', $.mage.catalogAddToCart, {
        submitForm: function(form) {
            var productSku = product_sku;
            //Rest of codes
        }
    });
    return $.Vendor.MyAddToCart;
});
```

I can get the correct SKU, but how about other product attributes? Seems using global variable method is not so good in this case. Is there any internal methods to get the product attributes inside `MyAddToCart` without using global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close, you can pass PHP to the JS inside the `x-magento-init` command:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "MyAddToCart": {
                "sku": "<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getSku(); ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

To access it in your JS you need to add the following:

```
return function (config) {
    var sku = config.sku;
}
```

I don't have time to test it so let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Which file should I put the `return function` into?

Comment: @PYYick Your JS file sorry - `app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/MyAddToCart.js`

Comment: You can use `console.log(config)` to see the whole config.

Comment: In my case, I can access the value by this.options.sku . I don't know why but it works even I changed the variable name :)